# Sending Rails app live with Nginx on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx

we are following [this nginx guide](http://www.modrails.com/videos/passenger_nginx.mov) and we want to send our Rails app LIVE right now. what do we replace `rails_env development` with at 2:26 in order to send it live and not to development??

Answer (score 1):

Set it to production if you want it to run in the production environment.

Comment: we have another issue. our current test database is sqlite3, but we have finished testing. we want to deploy ou rapp right now, and want to use MySQL as our production database. we dont understand how to switch from sqlite3 to mysql and dont know if we have to configure MySQL on the linode ubuntu box were using as our hosting platform.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to install mysql on your linode and modify your database.yml production settings accordingly.